# How to declare "nextval('testing_thing_thing_id_seq'::regclass)" as default value for column "thing_id" in postgres table "testing_thing"?

Tags: sql, postgresql, auto-increment, nextval

In my postgres db there is a table called `testing_thing`, which I can see (by running `\d testing_thing` in my psql prompt) it is defined as

```
                                        Table "public.testing_thing"

    Column    |       Type        | Collation | Nullable |                       Default                       

--------------+-------------------+-----------+----------+-----------------------------------------------------

 thing_id   | integer           |           | not null | nextval('testing_thing_thing_id_seq'::regclass)

 thing_num  | smallint          |           | not null | 0

 thing_desc | character varying |           | not null | 

Indexes:

    "testing_thing_pk" PRIMARY KEY, btree (thing_num)
```

I want to drop it and re-create it exactly as it is, but I don't know how to reproduce the

```
nextval('testing_thing_thing_id_seq'::regclass)
```

part for column `thing_id`.

This is the query I put together to create the table:

```
CREATE TABLE testing_thing(
   thing_id integer NOT NULL, --what else should I put here?
   thing_num smallint NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT 0,
   thing_desc varchar(100) NOT NULL
);
```

what is it missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a `DEFAULT` to the column you want to increment and call `nextval()`:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE testing_thing_thing_id_seq START WITH 1;

CREATE TABLE testing_thing(
   thing_id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('testing_thing_thing_id_seq'),
   thing_num smallint NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT 0,
   thing_desc varchar(100) NOT NULL
);
```

**Side note**: Keep in mind that attaching a sequence to a column does not prevent users to manually fill it with random data, which can create really nasty problems with primary keys. If you want to overcome it and do not necessarily need to have a sequence, consider creating an identity column, e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE testing_thing(
   thing_id integer NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
   thing_num smallint NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT 0,
   thing_desc varchar(100) NOT NULL
);
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=2be8e60ac6eac70e2eb27012d7df78b4)

Comment: @Tms91 you have to create a sequence manually (I added it to my fiddle), e.g.: `CREATE SEQUENCE testing_thing_thing_id_seq START WITH 1;`

Comment: The table was probably created with `thing_id serial not null primary key` rather than manually creating and attaching the sequence. And that would mean that the sequence is owned by `testing_thing`.

Comment: @mu is too short, but `thing_id` is not my table primary key, `thing_num` is.

Comment: @Tms91 Then probably `thing_id serial not null`, the main point was that it looks like what the `serial` pseudo-type would do.

Comment: @Tms91 `serial` isn't a standard data type and I wouldn't recommend its usage, although it seems pretty practical. If you can afford not having a sequence, consider an identity column instead - it has the same effect, it is a SQL standard and it is much safer. Cheers! .

Comment: @mu is too short if you wish to type your advice about `serial` as answer I will be happy to upvote it

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE testing_thing(
   thing_id integer NOT NULL ,
   thing_num smallint NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT 0,
   thing_desc varchar(100) NOT NULL
);

CREATE SEQUENCE IF NOT EXISTS testing_thing_thing_id_seq 
    INCREMENT 1
    START 1
    MINVALUE 1
    MAXVALUE 100
    CACHE 1
    OWNED BY testing_thing.thing_id;

ALTER TABLE testing_thing
  ALTER COLUMN thing_id SET DEFAULT nextval('testing_thing_thing_id_seq'::regclass);
```

Comment: Your answer is just code. Perhaps you could explain a litle bit what is done and why

Comment: first you create the table (without sequence on it) and the sequence , then you update the table with the sequence